# не правильно работает код, по крайней мере не так задумывалось

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Я написал рекурсивную функцию, и она выполняется больше раз чем надо, уже есть результат, но она как-то всё сбрасывает до начала работы.

вот код:

```
def multiply(string):   

    if "*" in string:

        string=string.split(" ")

        multiply_index=[i for i, j in enumerate(string) if j=="*"]

        for i, j in enumerate(string):
            multiply_result=int(string[multiply_index[i]-1])*int(string[multiply_index[i]+1])

            del string[multiply_index[i]-1]

            del string[multiply_index[i]]

            string[multiply_index[i]-1]=str(multiply_result)

            string= " ".join(string)                   

            multiply(string)

            if len(multiply_index)==1:

                break

        print(string)

    else:

        string=" ".join(string)

        return string

multiply("3 * 3 * 2")
```

Comment: А как задумывалось?

Comment: "Смешались в кучу кони, люди..." (с) У вас и обработка строки в цикле, и "типа" рекурсия (причём результат её игнорируется). Вы уж как-нибудь определитесь с алгоритмом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, как мне кажется, делаете много лишних действий. Если подумать, алгоритм для вашей задачи довольно простой.

Придерживаясь вашей же стилистики...
Вот вариант с рекурсией:

```
def multiply(string):
    if "*" in string:
        expression = string.split(" ")
        multiply_index = expression.index("*")
        multiply_result = int(expression[multiply_index-1]) * int(expression[multiply_index+1])

        return multiply(' '.join(expression[:multiply_index-1] + [str(multiply_result)] + expression[multiply_index+2:]))
    return string
```

А вот тот же алгоритм, но используя только цикл:

```
def multiply(string):
    expression = string.split(" ")
    while "*" in expression:
        multiply_index = expression.index("*")
        multiply_result = int(expression[multiply_index-1]) * int(expression[multiply_index+1])

        expression = expression[:multiply_index-1] + [str(multiply_result)] + expression[multiply_index+2:]
    return " ".join(expression)
```

Функции работают даже с выражениями которые содержат и другие операции, вычисляя в них только умножение (вдруг вы калькулятор пишете).
Например для `multiply("7 - 3 * 5 + 2 * 7")`
результатом будет строка `7 - 15 + 14`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогли. Да я пишу калькулятор, для каждого действия будет подобная функция ,потом в главной функции будут они все объеденены. Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Потом объединить не очень получится. Ведь операции умножения-деления - равнозначны по приоритетам. Как и операции сложения-вычитания. Так что каждую пару надо одновременно обрабатывать в одной функции. Т.е. должна быть, к примеру, функция `mul_div` вместо `multiply`, которая обрабатывает сразу и умножение, и деление.

Comment: Всё поличилось. add(subtraction(division(multiple (string)))). только к сожалению не придумал как сделать обработку скобок

Comment: ахах а, вы были правы, но я уже переделал теперь всё работает, даже со скобками